# Can I use e10s (multiprocess) in Firefox Dev Edition?

Tags: firefox, multi-processor, firefox-developer-edition

I am using Firefox Developer Edition because I need the browser toolbox features for my work creating add-ons.  However, I really like speed boost from the new experimental multi-process feature (electrolysis/e10s).

I've seen lots of articles showing going to `about:preferences` in Nightly, but that check box doesn't appear in Dev Edition.  I was thinking it might be possible to enable it via `about:config`...can I do that?  I seem to remember a way, but can't find it anymore.

Is there any way to get E10S in other versions of Firefox besides Nightly?

Comment: It sounds like the experimental feature has not made it to that release yet.  Can't enable a feature that has not been added yet.

Comment: @Ramhound : That is what I would expect, except that I've used it before in Aurora.  I guess you're suggesting it's been removed.  That would be sad.

Comment: Similar, with an accepted answer: http://superuser.com/q/1029400/84988

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get E10S in other versions of Firefox besides Nightly?

Now, yes:

- [Multiprocess Firefox - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox)
- [Electrolysis/Firefox - MozillaWiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis/Firefox)
- [Firefox 48 finally enables Electrolysis for multi-process goodness | Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/06/firefox-48-electrolysis-download-details/) (2016-06-08)

Answer (score 0):

The settings you're looking for are `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` and `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable`.