# How to enable electrolysis (e10s) on Mozilla Firefox Beta

Tags: firefox

How to enable electrolysis for [Firefox beta](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/)? They're testing it right now via A/B testing on this feature so it's there. It should be possible to enable it manually (certainly through about:config) but I didn't find anything that actually works for Firefox Beta 44.

Mozilla document on https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis how to enable electrolysis for Nightly build, but not for beta.

EDIT: It's now documented on https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Enabling_and_Disabling_Electrolysis_on_Beta

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In about:config (see http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config to learn how to use "about:config")

Set `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` to `true`

On your next restart, e10s should be active. To verify that it is active, go to about:support and look for a number higher than 0 in "Multiprocess Windows".

[image]

Answer (score 25):

To summarize it:

In the address bar, write `about:config`, answer yes to the warning, search for variables line after line, and set the values to those after equal sign:

**browser.tabs.remote.autostart=true**

**extensions.e10sBloc­kedByAddons=false**

**extensions.e10sBloc­ksEnabling=false**

Create a variable (or key for those who think of this as some kind of registry) with a boolean value (Right click in the pane with search results, Select "new"):
**browser.tabs.remote.force-enable=true**

Restart the browser, then go to `about:support` and as @gagarine mentioned, in Multiprocess Windows, there should be "1/1 (user activated)".

**Update:**

Now in Firefox 54, you should have Electrolysis on by default. You should check out the option **dom.ipc.processCount** and if it is still 1, turn it higher to match the physical core count, or if you know you use hyperthreading (most Core i7 and i3 on desktop, most Core i5 and i7 in laptops, AMD Ryzen), it is double that. (You can also see that in Task Manager under performance on Windows and in `top` or `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor` on Linux).

Read more about it here: https://medium.com/mozilla-tech/the-search-for-the-goldilocks-browser-and-why-firefox-may-be-just-right-for-you-1f520506aa35

Answer (score 12):

Mine shows "0/1 (Disabled by add-ons)". It seems some accessibility options may disable this feature.

According to [Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Force_Enable), you can force it to enable in these cases by also adding **browser.tabs.remote.force-enable** on about:config and setting it to **true**, but it also alerts it may break something.

Answer (score 5):

This is how to force Firefox 48 and above to enable Electrolysis.

1. In the location bar write `about:config` and tap `Enter` key
2. Search for `browser.tabs.remote.autostart`, and change its value to `true`
   [image: <code>browser.tabs.remote.autostart</code>=<code>true</code>]
3. Right click anywhere in the table and add a boolean value, and name it `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` with value of `true`
   [image: <code>browser.tabs.remote.force-enable</code>=<code>true</code>]
4. Restart your browser
5. Go to `about:support` from the location bar to confirm the enablement by checking for **Multiprocess Windows** row in **Application Basics** table.