# I enabled Multiprocess Windows in Firefox 49, but still 1 process

Tags: firefox, multi-processor

in **Firexfox 49** I just enabled `Multiprocess Windows`.

*`browser.tabs.remote.autostart` set to `true`, also `extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons` to `false` and adding `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` equal to `true`.*

But still 1 process for Firefox.

- *I disabled all `add-on`s but `Firebug`, btw.*
- *I'm using `Windows 10 - 64bit`*

I did something wrong?

**Update**

Here is `about:support` screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What does your "Multiprocess Windows" value show up as in `about:support`? If it's any consolation, I couldn't get this working either.

Comment: Have a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/1029400/how-to-enable-electrolysis-e10s-on-mozilla-firefox-beta/1108314#1108314 it should help

Comment: @AdamKalisz I've tried all of those steps and run into the same problem as OP. Same system (Win10 x64) and same Firefox release. Multiprocess Windows shows as "1/1 (Enabled by user)" as it should; it just doesn't actually run more than one process.

Comment: I just added screenshot of `about:support` tab

Comment: I don't know much more about it, but it was rather complicated, when more processes actually get started. Firebug is unknown: http://arewee10syet.com/ if it works, try disabling it as well maybe? Multi-content process is in the works so it seems: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis/Multiple_content_processes (Linked from https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Schedule_and_Status)

You are still running more threads so it isn't that bad.

Comment: @AdamKalisz I just disabled `Firebug` too, but no success. I just wondering any user of that 1% could get multiple process or not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like enabling `e10s` not working on `Firefox` for now, so I just installed `Firefox beta` (*currently v50*) and after disabling all add-ones, I could get 2 processes for Firefox (*by following mentioned steps in my question*).

BTW, As you know, `Firebug` doesn't work if you enable `e10s` and you have to work with Firefox's dev console. *it's not bad, but maybe a little uncomfortable if you are Firebug guy*

More info about that: [Firebug 3 & Multiprocess Firefox (e10s)](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/12/firebug-3-multiprocess-firefox-e10s/)

Answer (score 0):

Windows aside, for a moment, with the current implementation of e10s it's normal to find:

- no more than one process for all tabs

– https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=211233#c12 describes the *content* process in a FreeBSD context.

Comment: If you use `Beta` or `Developer edition` or even `Nightly`, you can have one process for each tab.

Comment: Thanks @MehdiDehghani (aside: none of those are ported to FreeBSD; re: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/53082/#post-297965 I might try (on FreeBSD) a version for Linux).